# How to print all dependencies in meson?

Tags: meson-build

I checked out a gtk project inside a docker and during meson build found many dependencies are missing eg. libwayland-dev, libxrandr-dev...

Because meson fails at the first missing dependency, I had to redo this over and over to get install the entire list of dependencies that will be looked for using pkg-config. And, in projects with multiple git submodules, this becomes a lengthy process.

Wondering if I'm doing this whole thing wrong or if there is a way to get to the complete list of dependencies.